# Spring JavaMailSenderImpl send base64 image html

Tags: java, image, spring, email, base64

I'm sending a mail using JavaMailSenderImpl on Spring. I'm trying to embed a base64 image to the mail as follows.

```
mimeMessageHelper.setTo("some@someone");
mimeMessageHelper.setReplyTo("some@someone");
mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("some@someone");
mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("someSubject");
mimeMessageHelper.setText("<img src='data:image/png;base64,imagebase64here'>",true);
```

image is not appearing in the mail. What am I doing wrong here?